# partial with image tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-for

I am having difficulty sending image info to a partial while using `content_for`.

Here is my code:

`home.html.erb`

```
<% content_for :imageName do %>
  <%= image_tag "profile_alexpic.jpg",
      :class => "img-circle pull-xs-left",
      :width => "100",
      :height => "100" %>
<% end %>

<%= render 'layouts/jumbo' %>
```

`_jumbo.html.erb`

```
<%= content_for(:imageName) %>
```

Everything is rendering exactly how I want it, but the text `profile_alexpic.jpg` is output next to the image. How do I prevent this?

Comment: You can post codes here instead of linking gist.

Comment: Relevant documentation for answerers: [`image_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag), [`content_for`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper/content_for).

Comment: I can’t see anything in your code that could cause that text to be output. Can you copy and paste the generated HTML for that section, by viewing the source of the web page when you visit it? You might find something like `<img src="profile_alexpic.jpg" …> profile_alexpic.jpg`, or the generated HTML might be different.

Comment: Thanks @RoryO'Kane, viewing the page source helped me figure out the error.